# Is there a way to add a condition to not allow empty inputs in React App?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am currently learning React JS, and to practice it I'm making a Todo List Web App project using it.
The App is working good, but I want to point out two important things which need to be fixed in it:

1. First is that it should not allow empty inputs to be pushed to the Firebase realtime database
2. Second issue is that after clicking on Add Todo Button in the App, it should clear the input box also.

Here is the code of my Web App:

App.js code:

```
    export default function App() {
return (
    <div className="App">
        <h1 className="App-heading">Todo List Web App</h1>
        <p className="App-subHeading">Developed by: <strong><i>Abdul Basit Mehtab</i></strong> & Powered by: <strong><i>Firebase</i></strong></p>
        <br />
        <Form />
        <TodoList />
    </div>
);
    }
```

Todo.js component code:

```
    export default function Todo({ todo }) {
const deleteTodo = () => {
    const todoRef = firebase.database().ref('Todo').child(todo.id);
    todoRef.remove();
};

const completeTodo = () => {
    const todoRef = firebase.database().ref('Todo').child(todo.id);
    todoRef.update({
        complete: !todo.complete,
    });
};

return (
    <div className="todoDiv">
        <h1 className={todo.complete ? 'complete' : ''}>{todo.title}</h1>
        <button onClick={deleteTodo} className="styledButton extraBtnstyle">Delete</button>
        <button onClick={completeTodo} className="styledButton extraBtnstyle">Complete</button>
    </div>
);
    }
```

TodoList Component Code:

```
    export default function TodoList() {
const [todoList, setTodoList] = useState();

useEffect(() => {
    const todoRef = firebase.database().ref('Todo');
    todoRef.on('value', (snapshot) => {
        const todos = snapshot.val();
        const todoList = [];
        for (let id in todos) {
            todoList.push({ id, ...todos[id] });
        }
        setTodoList(todoList);
    });
}, []);

return (
    <div>
        {todoList
         ? todoList.map((todo, index) => <Todo todo={todo} key={index} />) : ''}
    </div>
);
    }
```

Form.js Component Code:

```
    export default function Form() {
const [title, setTitle] = useState('');

const handleOnChange = (e) => {
    setTitle(e.target.value);
};

const createTodo = () => {
    const todoRef = firebase.database().ref('Todo');
    const todo = {
        title,
        complete: false,
    };

    todoRef.push(todo);
};

return (
    <div>
        <input type="text" onChange={handleOnChange} value={title} className="inputbox" />
        <br /><br />
        <button onClick={createTodo} className="styledButton">Add Todo</button>
    </div>
);
    }
```

Comment: You're using `<input>` elements, so just set a validation rule on it?

Answer (score 0):

This is the approach I use:

```
if(str.trim().length == 0) return;
```

It's pretty simple to validate empty input.

Comment: Can you please tell according to the context of my code above? it's hard to understand the correct implementation of this code in mine one.

Comment: @AbdulBasit Here:


`const createTodo = () => {

    const todoRef = firebase.database().ref('Todo');
    const todo = {
        title,
        complete: false,
    };


   if (todo.title.trim().length == 0) return;

    todoRef.push(todo);
};`

Answer (score 0):

Remember: you're still just writing web content, even if you're only writing React code. That `<input>` code will become a normal HTML form input element, and input elements in HTML5 can be given validation attributes. Adding [required="required"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/required) should automatically prevent your form submit button from doing anything until the element has an actual value, and if you need more elaborate validation, there's always the [pattern](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#htmlattrdefpattern) attribute.